# Public variable value is not reset

Tags: xml, vba

[image]I am using a public "reportName" variable on few procedures ( like the following example ) those procedures convert xml file to excel sheet. the problem is that the value of the "reportName" variable always remain as "Items" any idea why ?

```
Option Explicit
Global reportName As String

'Refresh Items
Public Sub s_refresh_Items()

    'Declare our variables
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim reportBytes As String
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60: Set xmlDoc = New 
    SXML2.DOMDocument60
      
    'Get Sheet by CodeName
    Set ws = getWorkSheetByCodeName("items")
      
    'Clear Excel contents
    If ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    ws.Rows("2:" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    'Show user form uf_loading_in_progress
    uf_loading_in_progress.Show
    DoEvents
    
    'Get report name
    reportName = "Items"
    
    'Call the function
    reportBytes = f_execWsSoap("/Custom/Logistics/Inventory/Reports/XX 
    INV005-Items List.xdo", reportName)
    
    'Check error
    If reportBytes = "-1" Then
    Debug.Print "Exit s_refresh_Items"
    uf_loading_in_progress.Hide
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    xmlDoc.Load (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads" & reportName & 
    ".xml")
    Dim myNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList: Set myNodes =   
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To myNodes.Length, 1 To 17)
    Dim myNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each myNode In myNodes
        i = i + 1
        Data(i, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 2) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_NUMBER")(0).Text
        Data(i, 3) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")(0).Text
        Data(i, 4) = myNode.SelectNodes("CATEGORY_CODE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 5) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_LONG_DESCRIPTION")(0).Text
        Data(i, 6) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_TYPE_NAME")(0).Text
        Data(i, 7) = myNode.SelectNodes("CREATION_DATE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 8) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_REVISION")(0).Text
        Data(i, 9) = myNode.SelectNodes("INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE")
        (0).Text
        Data(i, 10) = myNode.SelectNodes("PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG")(0).Text
        Data(i, 11) = myNode.SelectNodes("CUSTOMER_ORDER_ENABLED_FLAG")
        (0).Text
        Data(i, 12) = myNode.SelectNodes("UNIT_OF_MEASURE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 13) = myNode.SelectNodes("LIST_PRICE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 14) = myNode.SelectNodes("TP_TYPE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 15) = myNode.SelectNodes("MANUFACTURER_NAME")(0).Text
        Data(i, 16) = myNode.SelectNodes("MFG_PART_NUMBER")(0).Text
        Data(i, 17) = myNode.SelectNodes("MFG_ITEM_CREATION_DATE")(0).Text
            
    Next myNode
      
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(i, 17).Value = Data
    
    'Clean up
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    
    'Delete File
    Kill (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & reportName & ".xml")
    
    uf_loading_in_progress.Hide
    home.cb_items.Caption = Now
    MsgBox "Items refresh completed successfully."

End Sub


'Refresh Sales Orders History
Public Sub s_refresh_Sales_Orders_History()

    'Declare our variables
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim reportBytes As String
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60: Set xmlDoc = New 
    MSXML2.DOMDocument60
      
    'Get Sheet by CodeName
    Set ws = getWorkSheetByCodeName("history")
      
    'Clear Excel contents
    If ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
     ws.Rows("2:" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    'Show user form uf_loading_in_progress
    uf_loading_in_progress.Show
    DoEvents
    
    'Get report name
    reportName = "Items"
    
    'Call the function
    reportBytes = f_execWsSoap("/Custom/Logistics/Order 
    Management/Reports/XX DOO004-Sales Order History.xdo", reportName)
    
    'Check error
    If reportBytes = "-1" Then
    Debug.Print "Exit s_refresh_Items"
      uf_loading_in_progress.Hide
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    xmlDoc.Load (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads" & reportName & 
    ".xml")
    Dim myNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList: Set myNodes = 
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To myNodes.Length, 1 To 22)
    Dim myNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each myNode In myNodes
        i = i + 1
        Data(i, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("OPERATING_UNIT")(0).Text
        Data(i, 2) = myNode.SelectNodes("PARTY_NAME")(0).Text
        Data(i, 3) = myNode.SelectNodes("CUSTOMER_NUMBER")(0).Text
        Data(i, 4) = myNode.SelectNodes("BILL_TERRITORY_SHORT_NAME")
    (0).Text
        Data(i, 5) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORDER_NUMBER")(0).Text
        Data(i, 6) = myNode.SelectNodes("CUSTOMER_PO")(0).Text
        Data(i, 7) = myNode.SelectNodes("LINE_NUMBER")(0).Text
        Data(i, 8) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 9) = myNode.SelectNodes("LINE_CREATION_DATE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 10) = myNode.SelectNodes("FULFILL_STATUS_CODE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 11) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM")(0).Text
        Data(i, 12) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")(0).Text
        Data(i, 13) = myNode.SelectNodes("SHIPMENT_ORDERED_QUANTITY")
    (0).Text
        Data(i, 14) = myNode.SelectNodes("SHIPMENT_SHIPPED_QUANTITY")
    (0).Text
        Data(i, 15) = myNode.SelectNodes("FULFILL_ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE")
    (0).Text
        Data(i, 16) = myNode.SelectNodes("PAYMENT_TERMS")(0).Text
        Data(i, 17) = myNode.SelectNodes("CURRENCY")(0).Text
        Data(i, 18) = myNode.SelectNodes("UNIT_SELLING_PRICE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 19) = myNode.SelectNodes("EXTENDED_AMOUNT")(0).Text
        Data(i, 20) = myNode.SelectNodes("USD_AMOUNT")(0).Text
        Data(i, 21) = myNode.SelectNodes("DELIVERY")(0).Text
        Data(i, 22) = myNode.SelectNodes("HEADER_CREATED_BY")(0).Text
            
    Next myNode
      
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(i, 22).Value = Data
    
    'Clean up
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    
    'Delete File
    Kill (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & reportName & ".xml")
    
    uf_loading_in_progress.Hide
    home.cb_items.Caption = Now
    MsgBox "Items refresh completed successfully."
End Sub

'Execute WS soap
Public Function f_execWsSoap(ByVal reportAbsolutePath As String,  
    Optional reportName As String, Optional ByVal parameterNameValuesXML As 
    String)
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim base64reportBytes As String
    Dim reportBytes As String
    Dim httpReq As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim Response As String
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim faultCode As String
    Dim faultString As String
    Dim strSelectedItem As String
    Dim param1 As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
   'Get Home
    Set ws = Worksheets("home")
       
   'Get Credentials
    username = Worksheets(ws.Name).tb_username.Text
    password = Worksheets(ws.Name).tb_password.Text
    
    'Check if the username is null
    If username = "" Then
      MsgBox "Insert the Username"
      f_execWsSoap = "-1"
      Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Check if the password is null
    If password = "" Then
      MsgBox "Insert the Password"
      f_execWsSoap = "-1"
      Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Get report parameters
   
    If reportName = "Items" Then
    param1 = "P_ORGANIZATION_CODE"
    strSelectedItem = Worksheets(ws.Name).cb_item_organizations.Value
    End If
   
    If reportName = "Orders" Then
    param1 = "P_BU_NAME"
    strSelectedItem = Worksheets(ws.Name).cb_business_unit_so_history.Value
    End If
   
    'Url
    sURL = "https://org.com/xmlpserver/services/v2/ReportService"
    
    'Request
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Envelope  
    xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
    xmlns:v2=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/v2"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & " <soapenv:Header/>"
    sEnv = sEnv & " <soapenv:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  <v2:runReport>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <v2:reportRequest>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <v2:attributeFormat>xml</v2:attributeFormat>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <v2:attributeLocale>us-US</v2:attributeLocale>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <v2:reportAbsolutePath>" + reportAbsolutePath + 
    "</v2:reportAbsolutePath>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <v2:parameterNameValues>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "       <v2:listOfParamNameValues>"
    'If Not IsMissing(parameterNameValuesXML) Then
    '    sEnv = sEnv & parameterNameValuesXML
    'End If
    
    'Parameters - Added by me
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <v2:item>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <v2:name>" + param1 + "</v2:name>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <v2:values>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "           <v2:item>" + strSelectedItem + "</v2:item>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         </v2:values>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    </v2:item>"
    
    sEnv = sEnv & "        </v2:listOfParamNameValues>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    </v2:parameterNameValues>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   </v2:reportRequest>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <v2:userID>" + username + "</v2:userID>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <v2:password>" + password + "</v2:password>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  </v2:runReport>"
    sEnv = sEnv & " </soapenv:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"
    
    'Invoke the web service
    httpReq.Open "POST", sURL, False
    
    'Set header values
    httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    httpReq.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", False
    
    'Send request
    httpReq.send sEnv
    
    'Response
    Response = httpReq.responseText
        
    'Check Error
    faultCode = f_subStringByTag(Response, "<faultcode>", "</faultcode>")
    
    'Debug.Print "faultCode: " + faultCode
    If faultCode <> "" Then
      faultString = f_subStringByTag(Response, "<faultstring>", 
    "</faultstring>")
      If InStr(1, faultString, "SecurityException") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password."
        f_execWsSoap = "-1"
      Else
        MsgBox faultString
        f_execWsSoap = "-1"
      End If
      Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Get reportBytes
    reportBytes = f_subStringByTag(Response, "<reportBytes>", 
    "</reportBytes>")
     
    'Debug.Print reportBytes
    Debug.Print "START base64reportBytes " & Time
    
    'Decode reportBytes
    base64reportBytes = f_textBase64Decodefile(reportBytes, reportName)
    
    Debug.Print "END base64reportBytes " & Time
     
    'Clean up
    Set httpReq = Nothing
    
    'No error
    f_execWsSoap = base64reportBytes
    
End Function

'Get Worksheet by code name
Public Function getWorkSheetByCodeName(codeName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim Wks As Worksheet
    For Each Wks In Worksheets
        If Wks.codeName = codeName Then
           Set getWorkSheetByCodeName = Wks
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End Function

'Substring between 2 tags
Public Function f_subStringByTag(ByVal myString, ByVal startTag, ByVal endTag)
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    Dim subString As String

    'startPos
    startPos = InStr(1, myString, startTag)
    If startPos = 0 Then
     Exit Function
    End If
    
    'endPos
    endPos = InStr(1, myString, endTag)
    
    'subString
    startPos = startPos + Len(startTag)
    subString = Mid(myString, startPos, endPos - startPos)
    
    f_subStringByTag = subString
    
End Function

'Decode a text base64 in UTF8 and save to file
Function f_textBase64Decodefile(strBase64, reportName)
    
   Dim strFile  As String: strFile = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & reportName & ".xml"
   Dim b
    
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64": .Text = strBase64
        b = .nodeTypedValue
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open: .Type = 1: .Write b: .Position = 0: .Type = 2: .Charset = "utf-8"
                        
             If Len(Dir$(strFile)) > 0 Then Kill strFile
            .SaveToFile (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & reportName & ".xml")
           
            .Close
        End With
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Where did you declare `reportName` variable (`As Public`). Where do you change/reset its value, in order to check what you say? Is it declared on top of a standard module (in the declarations area)? Where its value is changed and what made you think that the code does not behave as it should?

Comment: the s_refresh_Items() procedure works perfect 
but then when i run the Public Sub s_refresh_Sales_Orders_History() 
i get error in line
Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To myNodes.Length, 1 To 22)
the error is :
"Run-time error 9:
Subscript out of range"

Comment: `myNodes.Length` has no meaning in VBA. If you need using the string length you should use `Len(myNodes)`. But I cannot imagine the purpose of using it in such a way... Can you clarify this need?

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of reportName to "Items" in the first line and then never set it to another value. Why would you expect it to change?

Comment: I can confirm, this is the correct answer.

Comment: I do change it on the next procedure to
reportName = "Orders"
and then i read different xml file by using similar procedure but then i always get "Object or Variable not set"

Comment: You should edit your original question to add all the relevant code. This should include the actual line that is throwing the error. We can only help you with the code you actually post.

Comment: the s_refresh_Items() procedure works perfect but then when i run the Public Sub s_refresh_Sales_Orders_History() i get error in line Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To myNodes.Length, 1 To 22) the error is : "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range"

Comment: It look like the code refuse to read the "Orders.xml" file and it's stuck on the "Item.xml" file

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is that you should put break point on the line and check the value of **myNodes**. You are not testing the return value of the immediately preceding line **Set myNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")**. Whatever the problem is, it had nothing to do with your use of a global variable.

Comment: you are right the initial problem description was incorrect 
When the reportName = "Items" The value of myNodes.length is 19929
When the reportName = "Orders" The value of myNodes.length is 0

i can attach sample of both "Items.xml" and "Orders.xml" but both have the same xml structure

Comment: **ReDim Data(1 To myNodes.length, ...)** is invalid when myNodes.length = 0. There's your subscript of range. Presumably because there is no "G_1" tag in "Orders.xml". How you address that situation is up to you.

Comment: "G_1" tag exist in "Orders.xml" this is why it's so strange

Comment: see attached Orders.xml ( image )

Comment: I found the problem.. for some reason and only on the "s_refresh_Sales_Orders_History()" sub the vba code doesn't recognize the following path. if i replace it to full path then it works any idea why ?
xmlDoc.Load (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads" & reportName & ".xml")